# How can I use a custom renderer to set the color of a switch by default?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently have this custom renderer to set the color of a switch in response to parameters.

```
class ExtSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null) return;

        ExtSwitch s = Element as ExtSwitch;

        this.Control.OnTintColor = s.SwitchOnColor.ToUIColor();

    }
}
```

I would like to modify this so I don't need to specify a parameter such as OnColor="Red". So there would be no OnElementChanged event

Can someone suggest to me how I can do set the OnColor to red with code in the renderer rather than on the parameter line of my XML in iOS?

Is there some other event that I can override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you upgrade the Xamarin Forms version in your project ( to 3.1) that is a Bindable Property now:

```
 <Switch OnColor="Red" />
```

You can also modify your renderer, and set the color, regardless of the binding:

```
 Control.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (204, 153, 255);
```

Or, in AppDelegate, apply to all Switches:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{

  // switch
    UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0x91, 0xCA, 0x47); // green
    // required Xamarin.Forms code
    Forms.Init ();
    LoadApplication (new App ());
    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the coloring is just done to the track color and it looks terrible :-(  in Android when I view the switch.  Is that AppDelegate just for iOS ?

Comment: AppDelegate is just for iOS. Your question was regarding iOS.

Comment: Yes but I would like to do it only for those switches for which I use a renderer.  So for example, one renderer that would make them red and one that would make them green.  Just really wanting to know if there's some method I could override where I could set the color of the switch other than the OnElementChanged method.

Comment: As it is in my response. If you update your xamarin.forms version, there is a bindable property for color.